# Вывести список приложений

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Приветствую. Пишу небольшую утилиту для windows. Требуется вывести список всех запущенных приложений и периодически по `Tick` таймера его обновлять. Например если запущено новое приложение вывести сообщение, если закрыто старое то вывести сообщение о том какое было закрыто. Вот событие по `Tick` таймера :

```
    List<string> ProcessOld = new List<string>();
    private void processGet(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
        try
        {
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process i in process)
            {
                if (i.MainWindowTitle != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (!ProcessOld.Contains(i.MainWindowTitle))
                    {
                        ProcessOld.Add(i.MainWindowTitle.ToString());
                        foreach (string SP in ProcessOld)
                        {
                            textBox1.Text += "Запущен процесс :: " + SP.ToString() + "\r\n";
                        } 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Работает вроде без ошибок но каждое приложение выводит по 2 раза и если будет запущено новое то выведет полный список из `ProcessOld` а не только новое запущенное, подскажите как это исправить? И подскажите как реализовать вывод сообщения о том что старый процесс был закрыт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такое решение :
Каждый раз при срабатывании `Tick` таймера выполняется `processGet`

```
    List<string> ALLinTIME = new List<string>();
    List<string> VivodProc = new List<string>();
    private void processGet(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
    var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
      try
        {
            ALLinTIME.Clear();
                foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process i in process)
                {
                    if (i.MainWindowTitle != string.Empty)
                    {
                         ALLinTIME.Add(i.MainWindowTitle.ToString());
                    }
                }
                foreach (string proc in ALLinTIME)
                {
                    if (!VivodProc.Contains(proc))
                    {
                        VivodProc.Add(proc);
                        textBox1.Text += "Запущен процесс :: " + proc.ToString() + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
                foreach(string _proc in VivodProc)
                {
                    if (!ALLinTIME.Contains(_proc))
                    {
                        textBox1.Text += "Закрыт процесс :: " + _proc.ToString() + "\r\n";
                        VivodProc.Remove(_proc);
                    }
                }
                textBox1.Text += "-------------------------" + "\r\n"; 
        }
```

Далеко не самое изящное решение, но работает как и хотел.

Answer (score 1):

2 раза выводит название каждого приложения потому, что вы в цикле по всем процессам выводите список `ProcessOld`. Нужно исправить код так:

```
List<string> ProcessOld = new List<string>();
private void processGet(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
    try
    {
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process i in process)
        {
            if (i.MainWindowTitle != string.Empty)
            {
                if (!ProcessOld.Contains(i.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    ProcessOld.Add(i.MainWindowTitle.ToString()); 
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (string SP in ProcessOld)
            textBox1.Text += "Запущен процесс :: " + SP.ToString() + "\r\n";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы реализовать вывод сообщения о том, какое-то приложение закрылось, нужно пройтись в цикле по все процессам, добавить их в некоторый `List<System.Diagnostics.Process> processes` и затем пройтись по списку `OldProcesses` и для каждого элемента этого списка проверить, есть ли процесс с таким именем в списке `processes`.

Если есть, то удаляем элемент из списка `OldProcesses`. И в конечном итоге в списке останутся только те процессы, которых уже нет в текущем списке процессов.